# IN Operator SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called NUMS with a single column n.
And I fill values 1,2,3,4,5,null in it.

Now a query

```
SELECT n FROM Nums 
 WHERE n IN (1, 2, null)
```

In this case I guess it's converted to

```
SELECT n FROM Nums 
 Where n = 1 OR n = 2 OR n = null
```

I am also comparing n with a null value which should yield unknown and it should return an empty set.But it's returning 1,2 (null is not returning, although included in IN operator)

Now a query

```
SELECT n FROM Nums WHERE n NOT IN(1, 2, null)
```

...gets converted to:

```
SELECT n FROM Nums 
 Where n!=1 AND n!=2 AND n!=null
```

Here what I said above works and it does not return anything.

Can anyone explain in detail what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I have found the answer

```
SELECT n FROM Nums    
WHERE n NOT IN (1, 2, null)
```

evaluates to

```
SELECT n FROM Nums  
n!=1 AND n!=2 AND n!=null
```

The outcome of last comparison will always be UNKNOWN.
and the truth table of AND shows that as soon as one Unknown is invloved in it (U,T)(U,F),(U,U) the reult can only be U or F (U=Unknown, F=False)  and hence it will not be included in the result set.

In case of

```
SELECT n FROM Nums
WHERE n IN (1, 2, null)
```

equates to

```
SELECT n FROM Nums
WHERE n = 1 OR n =2 OR n=null
```

Now for the row with n=1, the operation n=1 will come as true
and for the row with n=2, the operation n=2 will come as true
and for all rows n=null will be unknown

So it gives 1 and 2 in the result set.
Hope u people liked it.
CAN ANYONE PLEASE MARK MY REPLY AS ANSWER

Comment: Only you can mark this as the answer, and you have to wait two days before you can.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `null = null` is always false the operator to use for null is `IS` or `IS NOT`
You can use the query below for the expected output

```
SELECT n FROM Nums WHERE n IN (1,2) OR n IS NULL
```

[Edit]Thanx @Buckwad

Comment: ALL predicate is ambuguous here due to "n" from 1st query never can be NULL

Comment: I think this is more simply written as:
    SELECT n FROM Nums WHERE n IN (1,2) OR n IS NULL

Answer (score 1):

> null is not returning, although included in IN operator

Because of the `n = NULL` evaluation; NULL can't *equal* NULL.  It would need to be handled as `n IS NULL` (or similar appropriate syntax) to return the NULL row/record.

Comment: NOT IN become != concatenated with AND
your query on set of 1,2,3,4,5,null should return all records, because:
1 != 1 (false) OR 1 != 2 (true) ->
2 != 1 (true) ->

and so on

Comment: n==1 OR n=2 OR n=null  
You see I am comparing all the n(s) with null  
So it should return empty set.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare directly with null. To find whether the value of a column is null, you must use something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT n
FROM Nums
WHERE n IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am also comparing n with a null value which should yield unknown and it should return an empty set.

it shouldn't
if you need in additional row filled with NULL values the best way imo is:

```
SELECT n FROM Nums WHERE n IN(1,2)
UNION
SELECT NULL
```

> Now a query
>
> SELECT n FROM Nums WHERE n NOT IN(1, 2, null)
>
> ...gets converted to:
>
> Here what I said above works and it does not return anything.

thats right, because nothing can be equal to NULL and for NULL comparison IS NULL statement is used

Comment: I am comparing each n (1,2,3,4,5,null) like this  
n==1 OR n=2 OR n=null  
All the n(s) will return unknown because n=null yields UNKNOWN for all n.  
It's like (true/false) OR (true/false) OR (Unknown) For each n.    
And this will yield unknown ultimately returning an empty set.

Comment: so? i know that and i answered that "it shouldn't"

Comment: SELECT n FROM NUMS WHERE n IN(null,1,2);
It is returning 1 and 2.
Please check.

Comment: so? i know this, but you want it returns 1, 2, AND NULL

>> "null is not returning, although included in IN operator"

Comment: why null will not get included ?
Answer:coz null=null will evaluate to UNKNOWN.

SIMILARLY 1=null should evaluate UNKNOWN so it should not return anything.

Do u know this ?

Answer (score 0):

If an `IN` list contains a `NULL` value anywhere, the result of the entire list is `UNKNOWN`

With the correct default of ANSI NULLS, when you compare `NULL` with `NULL` the result is not true, but `UNKNOWN`

Comment: SELECT n FROM NUMS WHERE n IN(null,1,2); It is returning 1 and 2. Please check

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT n FROM Nums  
 WHERE n IN (1, 2)
  Or n Is null
```

This will retrieve what you intend to get. As said by Mitch normally a comparison to Null yields `UNKNOWN`. This is because NULL itself is defined as an undefined value. It's like saying I lived in Nottingham, Birmingham and somewhere. Finding somewhere on the world map can prove a bit tricky as it is undefined.