# How to use IN Operator in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to use IN Operator in SQL Server

Here Is the table Structure

```
Create Table Sample(Id INT,Name Varchar(50))
```

While I am the Query like this I can get the Value

```
Select * FROM Sample WHERE Id IN ('74','77','79','80')
```

While I am executing the above Query I can't able to get the Records Related to that table getting error executing this error.

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @s='74','77','79','80'

Select * FROM Sample WHERE Id IN (@s)
```

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197736/in-operator-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong way

use the following way

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @s='74 , 77 , 79 , 80'

set @d = 'select * from arinvoice where arinvoiceid in('+@s+')'
exec (@d)
```

here `IN` operator use integers collection not string collection..

Answer (score 2):

you should use a function which gives back a result set ( takes a csv format and returns a table)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 

GO 

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Splitt] (@String    NVARCHAR(4000), 
                               @Delimiter CHAR(1)) 
RETURNS @Results TABLE ( 
  Items NVARCHAR(4000)) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @Index INT 
      DECLARE @Slice NVARCHAR(4000) 

      SELECT @Index = 1 

      IF @String IS NULL 
        RETURN 

      WHILE @Index != 0 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @Index = Charindex(@Delimiter, @String) 

            IF @Index <> 0 
              SELECT @Slice = LEFT(@String, @Index - 1) 
            ELSE 
              SELECT @Slice = @String 

            IF ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                             FROM   @Results 
                             WHERE  items = @Slice) ) 
              INSERT INTO @Results 
                          (Items) 
              VALUES      (@Slice) 

            SELECT @String = RIGHT(@String, Len(@String) - @Index) 

            IF Len(@String) = 0 
              BREAK 
        END 

      RETURN 
  END
```

and now you can write :

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @s='74,77,79,80'

Select * FROM Sample WHERE Id IN (select items from dbo.Splitt(@s,','))
```

Comment: it can be tuned up basically, but it is the right way. there are few situations which we should make "string sql execs". this is not one of them

Comment: @user1307481 is it slow or not fast enough? these are 2 different things... you have accepted the wrong answer(not saying youve should accept myne).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ADO.NET, you can avoid the magic string, just use SqlDataRecord.

Or if you are using SQL Server 2008, you can also avoid the magic string by using Table-Valued Parameter

Source: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html