# Retrieving all desired records from SELECT...IN subquery table when some values are NULL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `Table1` that contains a field `Id` and some other fields:

```
Id    SomeField
------------------
1     SomeValue
3     AnotherValue
```

I have another table `Table2` that contains a field `Id` corresponding to `Table1.Id`, and another field `Name`. Some of the `Name` values are `NULL`:

```
Id     Name
-----------
1      John
2      NULL
```

I am selecting data like this:

```
Select Id from Table1 where Name in (Select Name from Table2)
```

In this case, I am getting only John's `Id` (`1`) from the above query because of the `NULL` in the second row of `Table2`.

How can I get both `Id` values?

Comment: Updated title, added example Table1 data, rearranged and formatted question. @user1893874, please make sure this still conveys the original intent of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [IN Operator SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197736/in-operator-sql)

As it states, NULL = NULL will return false. Must use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

```
SELECT Id FROM Table1 WHERE Name IN (Select Name from Table2) OR Name IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes you are right, it is getting all the null Name values.